# Storing file-like objects and writing to multiple files

Tags: python, file, io

I got to know that file-like objects made in python from io.BytesIO or io.StringIO are not stored in the disk. Are they stored in the memory like variables? If not, where?
Also, is there a way to store them on the disk?

My code writes mp3 data to files which takes long time (30+ sec to write ~3.5mb). I planned to spilt the input data and write to files simultaneously. But I have no idea how to do this. Do I need to run multiple python scripts? I don't mind writing to different files and later read and edit the content. Can you point me to any references to start?

Comment: just use multi threading

Comment: @TERMINATOR Thanks a lot. Can you help me with the first part of the question?

Comment: yeah files are stores as buffers but they are automatically flushed to storage once the close instruction is used

Comment: they belong to the stdout stream i believe

Comment: you should know sometimes the flush fails and can cause an expetion so you should wrap it in a try except